# Oracle E-Business Suite HR, Value Sets: Where are the Where/Order By clauses stored in the database?

Tags: oracle

I am trying to query table validated value sets that do a certain kind of validation with the where clause of a value set in Oracle E-Business Suite HR. I haven't had any luck finding where these where clauses are stored in the database to query them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked too soon! This data is stored in FND_FLEX_VALIDATION_TABLES. The where clause is in column ADDITIONAL_WHERE_CLAUSE of this table.